# How to not reload webview when resuming app again?

Tags: android, android-studio, webview

I have made a webview app. Everything works well. However, when user hits back button, and opens (resumes) the app, it reloads the webview. How can I prevent it ?

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
            mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.org");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

so basically what you have to do is,save your activity state on saveInstanceState,

```
   @Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle) {
    mWebView.saveState(bundle);
}
```

and in your oncreate you just have to check if savedstate is null or not if null then loadurl else restorestate.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
            if (savedInstanceState != null)
      mWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
   else
      mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.org");
 }
```

this is how you get your state back whenever you have resume your app.

Comment: I did exactly what you have explained, but didnt work and no errors. Here is my java file https://www.hastebin.com/oqisurusez.scala

Comment: does this occur on orientation change?

Comment: Nope. It only re loads the webpage if hit back and open again.

Comment: i have refer [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html),its for user's browsing history they can't support it,only save state on orientation change.so you are nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: no, I am not talking about history. When user hits back button. it closes (not really closes, the app is still on background opened) and when opens again the webview refreshes.

Comment: Just check for other url.

Comment: Webview is still reloading on resume

Answer (score 0):

I Found The Solution :

Just Override OnPostResume Method 

And

Add This To Your Main Code

```
yourWevView.onResume();
```

It Worked For Me.

Comment: I override onPostResume like this @Override
    protected void onPostResume() {
        super.onPostResume();
      
    } in mainactivity java file but does not work. Where should i put yourwebview.onresume?