# How to not reload webview when resuming app again MAUI-ANDROID?

Tags: maui

I have a webview shows a webpage eg google.com. No code behind the project has no code at all.

The user navigates somewhere into the webpage and then taps the home button. When the user resumes the app, webview reload the initial page google.com. This occurs only on Android.

How to resume to the current page? How to avoid reload?

Any ideas?

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="mauitestsingle.MainPage">

    <WebView Source="https://google.com"/>

</ContentPage>
```

Some related questions in xamarin [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45403060/how-to-not-reload-webview-when-resuming-app-again)

Comment: Maui WebView doc says *"WebView defines a Navigating event that's raised when page navigation starts, and a Navigated event that's raised when page navigation completes."*. Use those to keep track of current page, then when reloaded, to return to the desired page. [I don't use WebView, so I can't help further.]

Comment: The issue is that the page reloads the initial page. Events are fired correctly. If for example you are filling a form, tap home button, and resume the app, webview reloads the page (even if i track the current page) and the form will be empty...

Answer (score 0):

I tested it on emulator. It doesn't have the issue you said. For MAUI, you can use the following code:

Page.xaml:

```xml
<ContentPage ...>

    <WebView Source="https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface"
             x:Name="web"/>

</ContentPage>
```

Page.xaml.cs:

```cs
public partial class NewPage1 : ContentPage
{
    public static WebView WebView;
    public NewPage1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        WebView = web;
    }
}
```

In Platforms/Android/MainActivity.cs, you can overload these two methods:

```cs
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        base.OnSaveInstanceState(outState);
        var webView = NewPage1.WebView.Handler.PlatformView as Android.Webkit.WebView;
        webView.SaveState(outState);
    }
    protected override void OnRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        var webView = NewPage1.WebView.Handler.PlatformView as Android.Webkit.WebView;
        webView.RestoreState(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Comment: OnRestoreInstanceState is not called. Any ideas?

Comment: The above solution is not working. If you navigate somewhere in the page eg follow a link, tap home, resume app, then webview reloads the 1st page. I dont know who upvoted the solution.

Comment: @IsidorosMoulas Did you test it on a physical machine?

Comment: Yes both, physical and emulator. Have a look a  similar question for android https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45403060/how-to-not-reload-webview-when-resuming-app-again

Comment: When you run the app on emulator, will it reload webview?

Comment: Yes always reloads the webview.

Comment: Yes both, physical and emulator reloads the initial page of webview on resume the app.

Comment: You can override the method of [Activity Lifecycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/activity-lifecycle/#activity-lifecycle-methods), and then add breakpoint to debug it to see which method is triggered when you tap home and resume app.

Comment: If I play around with the Activity parameters (NoHistory=false, AlwaysRetainTaskStake=true,...) the app doesn't close immediately and so if I am lucky the task is still open when I return. `OnRestoreInstanceState` is never called in my MAUI app. Only `OnSaveInstanceState`